# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound why does this keep popping up?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, web-development-server

This is my code pro.py which i have save in my Downloads:

```
 from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, session, redirect, url_for
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
    from wtforms import StringField,SubmitField

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'kmkey'

class SimpleForm(FlaskForm):

    breed = StringField('What breed are you?')
    submit= SubmitField('Click Me')

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def imp():

    form = SimpleForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['breed'] = form.breed.data
        flash(f"You just changed your breed to: {session['breed']}")

        return redirect(url_for('imp'))

    return render_template('imp.html',form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my html code imp.html which i have saved in my template folder which is inside Downloads:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     {% for mess in get_flashed_messages() %}
     <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role='alert'>
        <button type="button" class="fade close" data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close' >
          <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{mess}}
     </div>

    {% endfor %}

    <form method="post">
      {{form.hidden_tag()}}
      {{form.breed.label}}{{form.breed}}
      {{form.submit()}}
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when i run my python file on web it throws an error saying that 
 jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound:imp.html why does it happen like that??

Can anyone pls help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save it in `templates` folder not `template` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But i just have one clarification and; that is since i have just started to learn about Flask i just wanted to know what is the actual meaning of render_template and why is it required to save that particular html file in templates folder

Comment: render_template methods just render a html file to a specific route. It is required to save that html file in `templates` folder because when you initiate a flask app  `app = Flask(__name__)` , it also has a `template_folder` argument which is by default is `templates` folder in base app dir. You can change this behaviour if you want. `app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='path you want'`. Hope you understand this concept.

Comment: My pleasure. If it solves your problem, please mark it as an answer which helps other visitors when they face this problem.